# Fear and Reason in My Life With Master

Tags: my-life-with-master

In **My Life With Master**, it says on p.17 that:

> ...a particularly horrific and fearsome Master projects a *Fear* of 5 or more, and a weaker Master projects a *Fear* of 3 or less. High values for *Reason* relative to *Fear* make for shorter games, and *Reason* greater than *Fear* will increase the incidence of Connections responding favorably to emotional overtures from Minions

Aaaand...that's **it**. There's no other information on setting *Fear* and *Reason* except that on p.52 it says not to think that low values for them will make for a single-session game. So:

- What are the "default" values?
- What values work for various kinds of games?

  - Brutal games
  - Romantic games
  - Short games
  - Long games, etc.?
- Are particular ratios or pairs of values recommended? Or best avoided?

I know I'm late to the party, but I'm thinking of running MLWM for the first time very soon. And these seem like such powerful "dials" for setting up the game that I'd like to have some idea what I'm doing when I set them.

Answer (score 4):

I have found some information on settings for single-session play in a [thread on The Forge.](http://www.indie-rpgs.com/archive/index.php?topic=20767.0)

The Manifesto linked there is actually available [here instead.](http://ipressgames.com/manifesto.html)

For single-session play, the recommended values (by one individual) are:

> ...use *Fear* 2, *Reason* 3, with groups of three to four minions.

But this answers only part of my original question. Anyone have more generally applicable answers?

Comment: This Forge thread has a bunch of examples from actual play. It's still a draw-your-own-conclusions set of data though. http://indie-rpgs.com/archive/index.php?topic=10125.0